# How can I install, or run, a Mac-version of MATLAB on Parallels' virtual Windows platform?

Tags: matlab, osx-lion, parallels

Adam Lewis answered, "I have switched to running Matlab on Parallels Desktop on my 2008 Mac Book Pro and have Zero issues".  I have been unable to get a Mac-version of MATLAB v.7x to either install, or to run as a Mac program within Windows, on Parallels v7 virtual Windows7Prof, on my 13" MacBook Air.

Does it require a PC-version of MATLAB for the virtual machine?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it requires a Windows version.

If you install any software on a Virtual Machine, that software needs to be compatible with the guest OS (Windows in this case).

A virtual machine is exactly what it says: a virtual machine. So for any software, it will seem as if it's running on a real machine with that configuration (OS, CPU, RAM, ...). It doesn't really matter what the host machine is: that could be a Windows, Mac or Linux host or even your toaster.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you plan to run MATLAB on a Windows virtual machine, you need the Windows version of MATLAB.

... But consult a local expert for help. Installing the Mac version of MATLAB should be effortless.